# Is it true that there's no system call with more than 6 parameters in linux?

Tags: linux, system-calls

In `unistd.h` there's `_syscall0`~`_syscall6`:

```
_syscall6(type,name,type1,arg1,type2,arg2,type3,arg3,type4,arg4,type5,arg5,type6,arg6)
```

So is my conclusion right or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that function accepts 7 params (0-6) but this webpage says 6

From here: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html

> Earlier versions of Linux could handle
>   only four or five system call
>   parameters, and therefore the system
>   calls select() (5 parameters) and
>   mmap() (6 parameters) used to have a
>   single parameter that was a pointer to
>   a parameter block in memory. Since
>   Linux 1.3.0 five parameters are
>   supported (and the earlier select with
>   memory block was renamed old_select),
>   and since Linux 2.3.31 six parameters
>   are supported (and the earlier mmap
>   with memory block was succeeded by the
>   new mmap2).

Comment: So the length of parameters for system calls is **limited** ,right?

Comment: yes :) (and some more characters to bypass the character limitation)

Comment: 18 seconds slower, but looks like people like your answer more :) What are the chances we pasted exactly the same block?

Comment: lol, i really laughed at that :D Incredible indeed ! And i also saw the 7 param cite !

Comment: There has got to be a game in there somewhere - hide-and-seek-web or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted :

Ancient history

> Earlier versions of Linux could handle
>   only four or five system call
>   parameters, and therefore the system
>   calls select() (5 parameters) and
>   mmap() (6 parameters) used to have a
>   single parameter that was a pointer to
>   a parameter block in memory. Since
>   Linux 1.3.0 five parameters are
>   supported (and the earlier select with
>   memory block was renamed old_select),
>   and since Linux 2.3.31 six parameters
>   are supported (and the earlier mmap
>   with memory block was succeeded by the
>   new mmap2).